# ASP.net: Can you call ModalPopupExtender from GridView's edit button?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Can you call a modal pop-up from a `GridView` control's auto-generated Edit button? Can someone provide a link on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Matt Berseth has several posts covering this topic:

[Matt's blog](http://mattberseth.com/blog/modalpopupextender/)